# How to show Heads up notifications android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, push-notification

How to get a heads up notification.With below code i can only see three dots on status bar and a notification in notification bar.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bip);
Uri defaultSoundUri=RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.bip)
                .setContentTitle("Temp")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Please take a look at their documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: Well this is a silly one . Need to got to settings select my app and change app notification settings .After that headsup notifications were visible. But how facebook and other apps do with out this settings screwup .

Comment: I assume you are using a Chinese manufactured phone. There are indications floating around the webs that these have restrictions on notification settings that other phone makers to not put on their devices. Some apps are whitelisted, presumably based on their popularity and most likely based on paid agreements between phone maker and app providers. It is an additional revenue stream for phone makers after all, just like pre-installed apps.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was having the same problem, but I was using the newer `NotificationCompat.Builder()` call which requires a channel ID from a `NotificationChannel`.

The notification will only appear as a heads-up notification if the `NotificationChannel` is created with an importance value of `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH`:

```
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("channel01", "name", 
     NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);   // for heads-up notifications
channel.setDescription("description");

// Register channel with system
NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
```

Show the heads-up notification:

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel01")
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
        .setContentTitle("Test")
        .setContentText("You see me!")
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)   // heads-up
        .build();

NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: not working in android 10

Answer (score 17):

This code works for me:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_media_play)
                            .setContentTitle("My notification")
                            .setContentText("Hello World!")
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
```

Comment: For someone who wondering why the code above works, see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#Heads-up

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50296323/6161579

One important thing is, once you have registered the notification system wide like this:

```
// Register channel with system
NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
```

You can no longer change the the `IMPORTANCE`. In my experience changing the `CHANNEL_ID` after changing the `IMPORTANCE` for the notification allowed for it to show as a heads-up notification.