# How to show notifiction top screen in android?

Tags: android

I write this code to show a notification in android. But this notification is only shown in the status bar. I want when a message received show notifications on the top screen like telegram app:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvgD9.jpg)

My code:

```
        NotificationManager mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String offerChannelId = "offerChannelId";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String offerChannelName = "offerChannelName";
            String offerChannelDescription = "offerChannelDescription";
            int offerChannelImportance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") NotificationChannel notifChannel = new NotificationChannel(offerChannelId, offerChannelName, offerChannelImportance);
            notifChannel.setDescription(offerChannelDescription);
            mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(notifChannel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder sNotifBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext(), offerChannelId);
        sNotifBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_notifications))
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.baseColor_yellow))
                .setContentTitle("title")
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
        mNotifyManager.notify(1, sNotifBuilder.build());
```

How I do it? 
Min SDK is 21.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android show notification with a popup on top of any application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949501/android-show-notification-with-a-popup-on-top-of-any-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for you. Hope it may help you.

```
//build notification
NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
.setContentTitle("Ping Notification")
.setContentText("Tomorrow will be your birthday.")
.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL) // must requires VIBRATE permission
.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH) //must give priority to High, Max which will considered as heads-up notification
.addAction(R.drawable.dismiss, getString(R.string.dismiss), piDismiss)
.addAction(R.drawable.snooze, getString(R.string.snooze), piSnooze);

//set intents and pending intents to call service on click of "dismiss" action button of notification
Intent dismissIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
dismissIntent.setAction(ACTION_DISMISS);
PendingIntent piDismiss = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, dismissIntent, 0);

//set intents and pending intents to call service on click of "snooze" action button of notification
Intent snoozeIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
snoozeIntent.setAction(ACTION_SNOOZE);
PendingIntent piSnooze = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, snoozeIntent, 0);

// Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
NotificationManager notificationManager =
(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
/* Notification for oreo*/
            String channelId = "channel-01";
            String channelName = "Demo";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                        channelId, channelName, importance);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }
//to post your notification to the notification bar with a id. If a notification with same id already exists, it will get replaced with updated information.
notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Minimum SDK is Lolipop.

Comment: Accept my apology. I couldn't convey what I meant. I want when a message received show notifications on the top screen like a telegram. (an image added to post to Understand what I mean)

Comment: That is called heads up notification. Search for creating heads up notification.

Comment: You can check this SO post too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510861/how-to-show-heads-up-notifications-android